# Summation with skipping a term

Tags: series-expansion, summation

how do i sum the following in Mathematica: the m-th term is 1/(m^2 - n^2), the sum is over odd m and m <> n. i know the answer is -1/(4*n^2) or something like that. thanks !!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: can you give reference to this? a quick numerical simulation shows the sum is not `-1/(4 n^2)`?  `s=0;
n=10000;
{m=#;If[ OddQ[m]&&n!=m,s+=1/(m^2-n^2),0]}&/@Range[0,n];
N[s]`  compare to `-1/(4*n^2)//N`

Comment: oh, i forgot. n is also odd.

Comment: and i can hand calculate it by partial fraction. 1/(m^2 - n^2) = (-1/2n) * [1/(m+n) - 1/(m-n)]. so if you write things out, most terms cancel out leaving a 1/2n term. thus, the series sums to -1/4n^2.

Comment: What does `m<>n` mean?

Comment: m <> n means " m not equal to n". that is, m = n term is skipped in the sum to avoid infinity.

Comment: i tried Sum[1/(n^2 - m^2)  Boole[m != n], {m, 1, \[Infinity], 2}] and        Sum[If[m == n, 0, 1/(m^2 - n^2)], {m, 1, \[Infinity], 2}]. in both cases Mathematica just returned the command and not the actual sum.